# Cannot input new data into FeatureDataForm

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, feature-layer, wpf, arcgis-runtime

I am wanting to update the fields on my server using a FeatureDataForm. I have followed the documentation, but it still does not work. It also does not have the buttons in the form that say 'OK' and 'Delete' like the documentation does. Any help will be appreciated.

XAML (FeatureDataForm):

```
<Border x:Name="FeatureDataFormBorder" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,10,0" Width="300" Height="300" >
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="-45" BlurRadius="20" Opacity=".75" />
                </Border.Effect>
                <esri:FeatureDataForm x:Name="MyFeatureDataForm"  Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PanelGradient}" BorderThickness="12"
                                         IsReadOnly="False" LabelPosition="Left" />
            </Border>
```

XAML(MyMap):

```
<esri:Map x:Name="MyMap" Background="#FFE3E3E3" WrapAround="True"  MouseRightButtonDown="MyMap_MouseRightButtonDown" Extent="-9834972.92753924,4441899.425293319,-9833977.88119163, 4442762.485358352" Loaded="MyMap_Loaded">
                <esri:Map.Layers>
                    <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="MyLayer" Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" />
                    <esri:FeatureLayer ID="WaterValves" Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer/0" Renderer="{StaticResource MySimpleRenderer}"
                                                  OutFields="*" MouseLeftButtonUp="FeatureLayer_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseLeftButtonDown="FeatureLayer_MouseLeftButtonDown_1" DisableClientCaching="True"  Mode="OnDemand"/>
                    <esri:GraphicsLayer ID="CandidateGraphicsLayer">
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer.MapTip>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Stroke="Gray"  RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="#77FF0000" Margin="0,0,0,5" >
                                    <Rectangle.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect/>
                                    </Rectangle.Effect>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Rectangle Fill="#DDFFFFFF" Stroke="DarkGray" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Margin="10,10,10,15" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,20,30,30">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding [Address]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </esri:GraphicsLayer.MapTip>
                    </esri:GraphicsLayer>
                    <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="CalvertCity" Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_2/MapServer" />
                </esri:Map.Layers>                
            </esri:Map>
```

C#:

```
private void MyMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyFeatureDataForm.FeatureLayer = MyMap.Layers[1] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer;
        }


        private void FeatureLayer_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, GraphicMouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphic.Selected = !e.Graphic.Selected;
            if (e.Graphic.Selected)
                MyDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(e.Graphic, null);
        }
```

I believe this tells me that the map is editable:
[image]

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? Links would be helpful.

Comment: I use ArcGIS Runtime for WPF: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/samples/index.html#//02q2000000nt000000

Comment: Is editing enabled on the feature service you are referring to? (see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000393000000)

Comment: I posted a picture. That lock means that it is editable, correct?

Comment: the lock just means that everybody has access to the data. not necessarily that its editable. To check if editing is enabled you'll need to click on the services and then on the capabilities button on the left and then feature access in the middle. There you will see check boxes for create, query, delete and update. You'll want those checked to be able to edit.

Comment: Have you also tried posting this on the ESRI forums?

Comment: Alright I tried what you said @Craig and I got the error: Feature Access requires that the data be on SDE; other types of data sources are not supported.

Comment: @Clickinaway, I have not posted this specific issue, but I have posted others and they have always failed to respond.

Comment: @ Jlott, I hear ya; I feel bad when I see answered posts over that that are weeks if not months old.

Comment: @Clickinaway Yeah it is pretty ridiculous... Maybe it will get better in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this error that you reported *"Feature Access requires that the data be on SDE; other types of data sources are not supported",* I'm assuming that your data is stored in either a file GDB, personal GDB or shapefile.  If you are trying to edit data in a feature service, then your editable data has to be in an enterprise SDE database.   Here is a [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005mm000000) to a tutorial.